# making WebResponse GetResponse WebBot wait for redirect

Tags: webresponse, getresponse

I am making a bot that simulates a human user using a specific website.

When the user uses the site here is what happens

1. the user uploads a file by using the site's Browse button and then clicks Upload
2. the server responds immediately and the user sees a Please Wait gif
3. in the meantime the server is evaluating the file for errors. When it is done it redirects, and the user is take to a new .aspx page where they can correct the errors.

What I am not able to do w the bot is make it wait to get the redirect info.

The bot hits the website with this line of code (VB.NET)

```
Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = CType(Request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

The Response has the Please Wait gif in it, not the Errors.aspx page.  Somehow I need to make the bot, execute that line of code above then, sorta listen to the same port(?) and wait for the web server to send another response.

Ideas?

Comment: I can't just make the bot go to the Errors.aspx page, because the server redirects to 3 or 4 different error pages depending on what it finds in the file.  So I gotta get the redirect info.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just sleeping the thread, then hitting the url again, repeatedly till I got the response I wanted.